# Consulta en MySQL para obtener la diferencia en días entre una fecha y la fecha de hoy

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito realizar una query en MySQL. Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select MAX(Fecha)
  from cliente 
 where cliente.id = '1'
```

que me retorna el registro con la fecha máxima de la tabla cliente.

Necesito que la consulta me retorne la diferencia en días con la fecha actual del sistema. Ejemplo: en el caso que mi campo `MAX(Fecha)` sea `2016-11-01` y la fecha del sistema sea `2017-01-19`, ¿qué consulta me retorna la diferencia?

Comment: te he puesto una posible solucion con un enlace para que lo ejecutes el ejemplo y realices tus pruebas, espero haberte ayudado y saludos

Answer (score 11):

Para eso tienes la funcion DATEDIFF en MySQL, tienes que añadirle las dos fechas y te saca la cantidad de dias entre las dos

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2017-1-15', '2016-12-31');
```

Prueba a ver y me cuentas

Edito:
Para conseguir la fecha actual existe la funcion CURDATE() que te la devuelve. Bastaria con colocarla en el primer campo de DATEDIFF y te da los dias restantes hasta la fecha que le pongas:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE() , (select MAX(Fecha)
                             from cliente 
                             where cliente.id = '1'));
```

Comment: Tienes razón, edito la respuesta

Answer (score 5):

[`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) recibe tres parámetros:

1. Unidad de tiempo,
2. fecha incial y
3. fecha final.

De ser así, quedaría algo como:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, curdate(), (select fecha from cliente where cliente.id ='1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto con esta sentencia de **MySQL**:

`SELECT (DATEDIFF( now(),fechaCreacionContrasena)) as dias, FROM Usuarios WHERE Usuario = 'nombre_usuario';`

Se obtiene el numero de dias.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sSQL);
    if(rs.next()){
    noDias = rs.getString("Dias");  
        }
        rs.close();
        rs=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo ese ejercicio lo haría de la siguiente manera.

El **`DATEDIFF(FECHA_INICAL,FECHA_FINAL)`** esto devuelve el numero en día haciendo una resta y por lo que veo quieres la hora del sistema para eso existe una función llamada **`NOW()`** la cual te devuelve la fecha actual de tu sistema.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(Fecha))
FROM cliente 
WHERE cliente.id = '1';
```

Te coloco un enlace para que lo puedas ejecutar como la prueba : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/12